# How do i push notification repeated every 30 seconds

Tags: python, firebase, timer, push-notification

Currently I'm trying to send notification to my app by running python in background according to value in firebase. So, when the value in firebase turns from 0 to 1 it will sends notification. So right now I'm trying to send notification repeated every 30 seconds(as for testing). I use threading library for using Timer in my python code. But i got an error when running it.

pusher.py

```
import pyrebase
import threading
from pusher_push_notifications import PushNotifications
config = {
    'apiKey': "apiKey",
    'authDomain': "authDomain",
    'databaseURL': "databaseURL",
    'projectId': "projectId",
    'storageBucket': "storageBucket",
    'messagingSenderId': "messagingSenderId",
    'appId': "appId",
    'measurementId': "measurementId"
  }
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

beams_client = PushNotifications(
    instance_id='instance_id',
    secret_key='secret_key',
)

def stream_handler(message):
    print(message)
    if(message['data'] is 1):
        response = beams_client.publish_to_interests(
            interests=['hello'],
            publish_body={
                'apns': {
                    'aps': {
                        'alert': 'Hello!',
                    },
                },
                'fcm': {
                    'notification': {
                        'title': 'Alert!',
                        'body': 'It is starting to flood, please remove your car immediately!',
                    },
                },
            },
        )

    print(response['publishId'])
t = threading.Time(5,stream_handler)
t.starting()   
my_stream = db.child("FLOOD_STATUS").stream(stream_handler,None)
```

I received this error message.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 563, in start_stream
    self.stream_handler(msg_data)
  File "pusher.py", line 42, in stream_handler
    print(response['publishId'])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: stream_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `print(response['publishId'])` statement is outside of the `if(message['data'] is 1):` block where you define and populate it. The solution is to indent the `print` statement:

```
if(message['data'] is 1):
    response = beams_client.publish_to_interests(
        interests=['hello'],
        publish_body={
            'apns': {
                'aps': {
                    'alert': 'Hello!',
                },
            },
            'fcm': {
                'notification': {
                    'title': 'Alert!',
                    'body': 'It is starting to flood, please remove your car immediately!',
                },
            },
        },
    )

    print(response['publishId'])
```

Comment: got error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "pusher.py", line 42, in <module> t=threading.Time(5,stream_handler) AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'Time'

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but I'd recommend searching for the error message. Either way, the if the "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment" message is gone, that proves it was caused by the unindented `print` statement.